# How would pornstars recover if they converted?

Tags: pornography

Lets say porn stars or a prostitute or whatever else there are wanted to convert to Islam. How could they recover from sin if their images of nudity are permanently on the internet for everyone to view, people can see their nude body and this is a sin so even after converting to Islam despite having sins wiped away wont it still be a sin as they are still sheoung their nude body online?

Comment: Your question is based on a wrong assumption. Islam washes away all earlier sins. I'd assume we have relevant posts and answers on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Any sins they earn after conversion would still be counted as sins. Presumably after conversion they would stop showing their nude body publicly, and if not they should be informed that such behaviour goes against Islamic teachings.

What people do with the nude images that were generated before, insofar as they are completely out of the converts control, is irrelevant.

Comment: So if even if the persons nudes were still onlone if they stopped with their actions it is all ok. But doesnt the nudity lead men/women to commit other sins.

Comment: @NazreenShahid So what? How is it the convert's responsibility to stop other people from committing sins when they have zero control over them?

Answer (score 0):

Allah says regarding repentance, ((Except those who repent and amend and make manifest (the truth). These it is toward whom I relent. I am the Relenting, the Merciful.))
So three act!
1. Repentance from the sin
2. Amendment of the falsehood 
3. Manifestation of the truth

One should use all the means possible to delete these pictures! It takes a lon time, but a person have to be persistent. This is a human right! If one live in a country where human right is practice, they should use the law to let their picture taken away! If the person is very rich, they should even strive to make agreements and pay people money to delete their picture forever.

I know an Egyption singer who repented and made a deal with the music industry that she would sing islamic songs for them to record and sell, if they agree to delete all videos and song she made in the past! And after 20 years, you couldn’t find any of her old songs!

It’s not enough just to repent! One should strive to do good deeds that would amend the wrong deeds that was done before! A person has to promote the opposite! In this case the person need to preach against the wrong things they use to do to oppose the wrong message they were preaching before and so preach the right message! This is a justice social balance one is dutiful toward!

Allah knows best